# Nest JS Cache Manager returning undefined on get

Tags: caching, nestjs

The value is always undefined
I have registered the CacheModule in my Module

```
constructor(
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager: Cache,
  ) {}

  @Get()
  async fetchBuildings() {
    const value = await this.cacheManager.get('key');
    console.log(value);
    if (value) {
      return value;
    }

    await this.cacheManager.set('key', 'cached value');
    return 'new value';
  }
```

Comment: Currently having this problem too. Did you find out why?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issues and did the following which vixed it
I added the type

```
    const value = await this.cacheManager.get<string>('key');
```

And additionally I update my cachemodule register to include the store

```
import * as redisStore from 'cache-manager-redis-store';
CacheModule.register({
  store: redisStore,
  host: config.redisHost,
  port: 6379,
}),
```